# Can USB head cause a spark?

Tags: usb, pins, static-electricity, conformal-coating

I made a USB port in a gas detector prototype. I plan to keep a USB cable attached to that USB port forever. I silicone conformal coated the USB port pins on the PCB.

Can the USB head of the cable cause a spark when current runs through it, or is the spark expected to happen in the USB port pins only (which I already coated?)

Note: This port will turn on only if a gas is detected, rather than that it will keep off

Comment: *I silicon conformal coated* I guess that you mean silicon**e**. Silicon is a metal that is used to fabricate transistors and ICs. Silicon**e** or polysiloxane are **polymers** made up of siloxane (last bit from Wikipedia).

Comment: I mean "silicon conformal coating" like that provided from Konform company

Comment: Sparks generally occur when a connection is made or broken. This  includes "wiggeling" a (USB) connector in a socket as then the connection can be broken for a very short time causing a spark. I hope that you didn't coat the pins inside the USB socket as that would prevent a connection from being made. I guess that you mean that you coated the pins of the USB socket that are **soldered** onto the PCB. That would be OK but since that's a permanent connection, you would not get sparks there (unless the soldering connection breaks).

Comment: *I mean "silicon conformal coating"* Go look on their website: https://www.chemtronics.com/konform-sr and how it says: "Konform® SR Silicone Conformal Coating" So: Silicone, with an **e** at the end. The difference is important as silicon (no "e" at all) is an entirely different substance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just wanted to clarify that this port will turn on only if a gas is detected, rather than that it will keep off. In that case is the USB cable head still safe?

Comment: If you want a "no sparks guaranteed" then I personally would **not** use a USB connection. Instead, I would not use a connector. If possible I would use a long cable and have the connection elsewhere, far away from the gas. If you **must** have a connector nearby then consider a connector that is designed to be used near explosive gasses. That will no doubt be an expensive connector. As a compromise a semi-permanent solution could suffice like a pin-header connection or screw-terminals.

Comment: Okay, but leaving the connection plugged and stable is fine right?

Comment: Because if you extend say a cable away and gas leak is already spread everywhere, then the danger will be there too

Comment: I updated the silicone point, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: How can you guarantee that the connection will always be "plugged and stable"? There is always the possibility of a cable coming loose and being dislodged. If safety is required, make the connections permanent (soldered or crimped) and strong.

Comment: There are worldwide and usually countrywide laws that dictate how you can use powered electronics in the presence of a combustible gas mixture. It doesn't seem as if you are aware of this.

Comment: @Andyaka can you share a link offering more info on it please?

Comment: Not really - just go and look up zener barriers, spark ignition of gases etc..